# Split one column in SQL into multiple based on value in the column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split, multiple-columns

I need to separate (split) a column into multiple columns with TSQL.
I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Example:
[image: example]

Let's call it portfolio with bunch of stocks. Some dates might be overlapping (holding more than 1 stock at certain date).
I have multiple portfolios with different amount of stocks in each, so I need something like

```
for stock in stocks:
    select stock
```

And each stock (A, B or C) would go into its own column - if it's possible to dynamically change the name that would be great as well. So I'll have "stock - A", "return - A", "stock - B", "return - B", "stock - C", "return - C".

I will then do a simple arithmetic manipulations like column "sum".

Added:
The names of stocks and the quantity could be different portfolio-to-portfolio so it should be dynamic.

Thank you.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Once you update your question we'll know which pixels identify the portfolio, if any.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select date,
       'A', max(case when stock = 'A' then return end) as return_A,
       'B', max(case when stock = 'B' then return end) as return_B,
       'C', max(case when stock = 'C' then return end) as return_C
from t
group by date;
```

Comment: Thank you. What if i don't know the names 'A', 'B', 'C' in advance, so I can't hardcode it into query?

Comment: @user_unknown . . . Then you would have a *different* question.  Your question explicitly states:  "And each stock (A, B or C) would go into its own column".

Comment: Apologies, I did mention "I have multiple portfolios with different amount of stocks in each, so I need something like <for loop>". I thought that would help to understand better what I need. If you have any idea how to do it, I would appreciate help. Also, I'm happy to amend/edit my initial post if required. Thank you.